# Cordova android app user data size keeps growing

Tags: javascript, cordova, couchdb, cordova-plugins, pouchdb

#### Issue

Hi, in my cordova app I'm replicating data from remote couchdb to local pouchdb. When I launch the app for the first time it works fine, but when I close the app and relaunch it apps user data doubles. This size grows only for the second launch.

Please help me out. I'm Using: Server - couchdb , local - pouchdb , adapter : cordova-sqlite , ionic , cordova

#### Info

- Environment: **Cordova**
- Platform: **Android**
- Adapter: **Cordova-sqlite**
- Server: **PouchDB/CouchDB**

#### Reproduce

1. Build an cordova android app, in which create pouchdb instances of localdb (target) and remotedb (source), and replicate from remotedb to couchdb
2. Open application, let it sync completely
3. Once it syncs completely close the application and reopen it again
4. Now you can see the app data size keep increasing (almost  2x of size)

**Here is my code snipet**

```
var localPouchDB = new PouchDB(dbName, {
    adapter: 'cordova-sqlite',
    auto_compaction: true
  });


  var remotePouchDB = new PouchDB(remoteDBUrl, {
    auth: {
      username: username,
      password: password
    }
  });

  var replicateOptions = {
    live: true,
    retry: true
  };


 var replicationHandler = localPouchDB.replicate.from(remotePouchDB, replicateOptions).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Please provide some code snippet

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages.

Comment: @not2qubit  i have added code snipet please look at it

Comment: @JosephCho , please look at the code snipet

Comment: @Robert , i have adde the code snipet , please have a look at it, thanks in advance